# no signature of method after using metaclass method replacement?

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I have a simple domain class

```
package cat

class Cat {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I have a simple integration test to understand the meta method of groovy. I simply replace the save method and expect it to fail in the integration test. Then, i assert no cat record is saved in the database.

```
class CatTests extends GroovyTestCase{


    CatController controller = new CatController()


    @Test
    void testSomething() {                          

        Cat.metaClass.save = {

            throw new Exception("Asdasd")
        }

        shouldFail(Exception){

            Cat cat = new Cat(name: "asd")
            cat.save()

        }

        GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Cat.class)

        assertEquals Cat.count(), 0



    }
}
```

I get the error at this line  assertEquals Cat.count(), 0

```
 groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: cat.Cat.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: count(), ident(), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), getCount(), wait()
    at cat.CatTests.testSomething(CatTests.groovy:33)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 195ms
```

Why is it complaining that Cat no longer has the count method? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: ok putting this line in the end removed the error. GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Cat.class) dont know why though.

Comment: Perhaps you've simplified/omitted something for the sake of the question, but at face value this test looks very odd. You're basically testing a behaviour that only within the test class, i.e. the application throwing an exception when `save()` is called. Changing the test so that it attempts to save a `Cat` with a null `name` and then verifies that `Cat.count() == 0` seems like a much more useful test.

Answer (score 0):

ok changing the order of these two statements solved the problem.

```
assertEquals Cat.count(), 0

GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(Cat.class)
```

still not sure why though.